# How to show the time history of a signal down-sampled ? under the rate of 25Hz & 40Hz and find its DFT analysis?

Tags: matlab, frequency, dft, downsampling, amplitude

How to show the time history of a signal down-sampled under the rates of 25Hz & 40Hz and find its DFT analysis using Matlab ? The sample signal is in a data file ([sensor_data.mat](http://www.filedropper.com/sensordata)) its sampling rate is 1000Hz.

I can get the time history and the DFT analysis of the signal.

```
Fs = 1000; % sampling rate
T=1/Fs; % sample time
L= 20000; % lenght of signal
t=(0:L-1)*T; % time vector
figure(1)
plot(t,u)
grid;
title('Time History of the Signal')
% dft analysis
yf=fft(u);
w=[0:2*pi/L:(L-1)*2*pi/L];
figure(2)
plot(w/(2*pi*T),abs(yf))
grid
title('DFT analysis of the signal sampled at 1000Hz')
```

But how do I down-sample it ? I know Matlab has a function for it (downsample), but I'm not getting any correct answers.

Also how do I find the signals frequency range and amplitude over its frequency range from the DFT analysis ?

Thanks in advance, Please help !!

Comment: 1. Read the documentation for `fftshift`. 2. Explain why you think your results are incorrect -- what did you expect, and what did you get.

Comment: I want to downsample the signal not shift it !! And when I downsample the signal to 25hz : downsample('sensor_data', 25) and plot it I get the same time history plot before downsampling it.

Comment: You need to read the documentation for those commands, carefully. They don't work the way you're assuming they do.

Comment: The documentation for downsample just states to enter the value by which we want to downsample the signal. But given the value is in hertz, I'm assuming I need to convert it ?

Comment: That value is a factor. If signal `x` is sampled at 1000 Hz, then `y=downsample(x,10)` is sampled at 1000/10=100 Hz.

Comment: ok I did that. y=downsample(u,40) % downsampled at 25hz

Comment: but when I plot it, the signal looks the same before downsampling it ? Isn't it suppose to change ?Btw thanks for the help !

Comment: Just one question: the file you posted contains a variable `Fs` with a value of 11025. Are you sure the signals are sampled at 1000 Hz?

Comment: I was provided with the sensor_data.mat file which contains data in variable u. The sampling rate of 1000Hz was mentioned in the problem I was to solve.

Comment: Btw I got the downsample result and the DFT analysis of it. Thanks !

Comment: The file you provided contains variables `Fs`, `s1`, `s2` and `s3`. Glad you solved your problem. You may want to describe your solution as an answer, to help other users with similar problems.